# Always Getting redirected to SessionTimeOut page ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the SessionExpireFilter on each action to check if session has expired or not. If session has expired then it redirects the user to sessionTimeoutPage i.e. to membershipController and SessionTimeOut View

The filter looks like-

```
 public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [action executing].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {
            // check if a new session id was generated
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    if (ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    }

                    //HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId");
                    //mycookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue;
                    //ctx.Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);
                    //ctx.Session.Clear();

                    RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "SessionTimeOut");
                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Membership");
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);

                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The problem is I have a Membership controller login action method which also has that filter. It checks for the session expire and always find the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie and redirects to sessionTimeout page(Which has a link to login page) again and again

It would be great of somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution to work, you need to wireup the Session_Start event in Global.asax. If you wont do it, the Session.IsNewSession will always be true (that's the way the ASP.NET runtime works). Sometimes it is also necessary to store something (anything) in the Session.

Comment: I think its fine as I am doing the login again and its a nw session. The problem I have is with ASP.Net_session cookie is always there even in the new session

Comment: And it will be, believe me that is the way the runtime works (and performing login has nothing to do with Session), just wireup the event and check.

Comment: And did you try putting something into Session during that event? Just tested that in my environment and seems to be working fine.